# R odbc on oracle 11.2 ORA-00933

Tags: r, oracle, dbi

I am using the R DBI package to query a oracle database.
When using inner joins it gives me the following error.
Plain SELECTS without INNER JOIN works fine. Why?

Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1617: 00000: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

```
DBI::dbGetQuery(con_ora, "SELECT dat.LP_ZP_ID, dat.LP_TIMESTAMP_LOC, dat.LP_WERT, zp.ZP_ZAEHLPUNKT
                          FROM EDM_LP_DATEN dat 
                          INNER_JOIN EDM_ZAEHLPUNKT zp ON zp.ZP_ID=dat.LP_ZP_ID    
                          WHERE dat.ZP_ID = 111 AND dat.LP_TIMESTAMP_LOC >= TIMESTAMP '2021-01-01 00:00:00'")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's obviously wrong is this:

```
INNER_JOIN EDM_ZAEHLPUNKT
```

It is not `inner_join` but `inner join` (without underscore).

The rest of your query looks OK.